# Initializer list inside std::pair

Tags: c++, std, std-pair

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::pair<std::initializer_list<std::string>, int> groups{ { "A", "B" }, 0 };

int main()
{
    for (const auto& i : groups.first)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiles but returns segfault. Why?

Tested on gcc 8.3.0 and on online compilers.

Comment: For convenience: Godbolt links [with](https://godbolt.org/z/vWp6Ey) and [without](https://godbolt.org/z/B6x-Q_)  `std::pair`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` is not meant to be stored, it is just meant for ... well initialization. Internally it just stores a pointer to the first element and the size. In your code the `std::string` objects are temporaries and the `initializer_list` neither takes ownership of them, neither extends their life, neither copies them (because it's not a container) so they go out of scope immediately after creation, but your `initializer_list` still holds a pointer to them. That is why you get segmentation fault.

For storing you should use a container, like `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: It bothers me that this is compileable. Silly language :(

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I have a lot of beef with `initializer_list`. It is not possible to use move-only objects, so you cannot use list init with vector of unique_ptr for instance. The size of `initializer_list` is not a compile-time constant. And the fact that `std::vector<int>(3)` and `std::vector<int>{3}` do completely different things. Makes me sad :(

Comment: Yeah same... :(

Answer (score 3):

I would just add a bit more details. An underlying array of `std::initializer_list` behaves kind-of similarly as temporaries. Consider the following class:

```
struct X
{
   X(int i) { std::cerr << "ctor\n"; }
   ~X() { std::cerr << "dtor\n"; }
};
```

and its usage in the following code:

```
std::pair<const X&, int> p(1, 2);
std::cerr << "barrier\n";
```

It prints out

```
ctor
dtor
barrier
```

since at the first line, a temporary instance of type `X` is created (by converting constructor from `1`) and destroyed as well. The reference stored into `p` is then dangling.

As for `std::initializer_list`, if you use it this way:

```
{
   std::initializer_list<X> l { 1, 2 };
   std::cerr << "barrier\n";
}
```

then, the underlying (temporary) array exist as long as `l` exits. Therefore, the output is:

```
ctor
ctor
barrier
dtor
dtor
```

However, if you switch to

```
std::pair<std::initializer_list<X>, int> l { {1}, 2 };
std::cerr << "barrier\n";
```

The output is again

```
ctor
dtor
barrier
```

since the underlying (temporary) array exists only at the first line. Dereferencing the pointer to the elements of `l` then results in undefined behavior.

Live demo is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bvGJmw6Xta6UllUh).