# Using "auto" to deduce the type of a nested initializer list

Tags: c++, initializer-list, auto, type-deduction

I'm trying to use `auto` to automatically deduce the type of a nested `std::initializer_list`.

```
auto list = {
    {{ 0, 1}, { 2, 3 }},
    {{ 4, 5}, { 6, 7 }},
};
```

The actual type here is `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>>`, but when I attempt to compile it I get an error stating that `auto` cannot deduce the type. Is there any way to get `auto` to recognize such a construct?

I have a program where these initializer lists could be of arbitrary sizes and depths so hardcoding the types is not practical.

## Additional Info:

I found this documentation about initializer lists here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

> A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed. Having no type implies that template type deduction cannot deduce a type that matches a braced-init-list, so given the declaration `template<class T> void f(T);` the expression `f({1,2,3})` is ill-formed. However, the template parameter can otherwise be deduced, as is the case for `std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {})`, where the iterator type is deduced by the first argument but also used in the second parameter position. A special exception is made for type deduction using the keyword auto , which deduces any braced-init-list as `std::initializer_list` in copy-list-initialization.

The documentation seems to suggest that there is a special exception made for type deduction using `auto` so you would think that this would work... But it seems that when you use a nested list `auto` cannot deduce the type.

Comment: If you know the type, just declare it. Using `auto` seems lazy and like poor programming tactics used in languages that allow the `var` keyword. C++ is a typed language, which means that every variable has a type that cannot change once declared. Unless you're space-limited in how many characters your code file can have, just declare the type and be done with it.

Comment: @JoelTrauger read the last sentence of the question. The size/depth can vary. Hardcoding the type everywhere is not an option because the type is not always the same.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think even if you manually specified the type, you would get a 'dangling' initializer list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136795/initializer-list-inside-stdpair and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I'm not sure when they added it to the language, but the last comma is ignored by the compiler so it isn't dangling. If i manually specify the type this compiles in Visual Studio.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 That's not what I'm talking about, see the links I've posted.

Comment: Okay I will take a look, but it will compile if you specify the type manually.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I read the last line before I commented. Unfortunately C/C++ is pretty rigid once the code is compiled. I would seek out other languages that offer the sort of run-time flexibility you desire.

Comment: @JoelTrauger I'm not looking for runtime flexibility, this is compile time flexibility. `auto` deduces types at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: then if you're compiling hard-coded data, you know the data-type, and should declare it as such. Outside of a modification to the language and any known compilers I'm not sure you'll get an answer to this question.

Comment: @JoelTrauger The data may be hardcoded at input, but I'm trying to write a function that works on various data types. Hardcoding them in the function would totally defeat the purpose and make it entirely inflexible.

Comment: Try a different compiler, then. If you've exhausted them all, then it is a limitation of the language and you're not going to get any useful answers.

Comment: If you are writing a function, then why not template it?

Comment: @badfilms, That's basically what I'm trying to get at. I made a function like this: `template<typename List> f(const List& l)` but if you try to pass a nested list to it the compiler fails to deduce the type.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 are you always able to supply the depth of the nested inititializer list as a template parameter, like InitList<int, 3> list = ...?

Comment: @AllanCameron, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, could you explain?

Comment: I found some relevant documentation about how initializer list type deduction works and updated the question. From what the documentation says about `auto` and initializer lists I don't see why it wouldn't work, but it doesn't talk about how nested lists are handled.

Comment: @JoelTrauger It’s neither “poor” nor “lazy programming tactic”. It’s using strong typing as intended — as a boon for the programmer rather than a syntactic hurdle. Look at languages with superior type systems, such as Haskell and Ocaml, for how they treat this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a program where these initializer lists could be of arbitrary sizes and depths so hardcoding the types is not practical.

Then you need to fix that problem.

You should not think of braced-init-lists as a quick-and-dirty way of making arrays of values without having to think about their types. That's not their purpose. Their purpose is to initialize values. The type `std::initializer_list` is intended to be an intermediary phase in the process of initializing some type (which is why constructors that take a single `initializer_list` are given special meaning in list initialization).

If you want to have arrays of arrays of arrays of various depths and such, then you're going to need to figure out which type that construct needs to be and type it out. `auto` can only deduce a single level of braced-init-list; you'll need to specify the type(s) explicitly if you need deeper levels.

> there is a special exception made for type deduction using `auto`

Yes, there is. But it only applies to deducing a list for `auto` *itself*, not for anything that `auto`'s deduction would require.

In order for `auto list = {{1, 2, 3}};` to work, the compiler has to deduce *two types*: the type to be used for `{1, 2, 3}` and the type to be used for `list`. The deduction of the type for `list` requires deducing the type for the nested braced-init-list. But you *can't* deduce the type of a braced-init-list. Hence it does not work.

It should also be noted that, even if it did work, it wouldn't actually *work*. The reason being that the `initializer_list` inside of `list` would refer to a temporary array. A temporary array that would be destroyed at the end of the initializing expression. It's basically the same reason why `string_view sv = std::string("foo");` doesn't produce something useful.

Comment: Where is it documented that `auto` can only deduce single level braced-init-lists? I understand that this is probably true, but I can't find it stated explicitly in documentation anywhere.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: What kind of documentation are you looking for here?

Comment: Anything official in the standard or a credible site like cppreference that says what should happen if you try to deduce the type of a nested initializer list with `auto`. It says there are special type deduction rules for `auto` with initializer lists so it should work, but it doesn't specify why it doesn't work for nested lists.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: "*Literally anything official in the standard that says what should happen if you try to deduce the type of a nested initializer list with auto.*" That's not how a standard works. There's not a special rule for nested braced-init-lists used specifically to deduce an `auto` variable. There's a special rule for a braced-init-list used for `auto` variables, but the braced-init-lists *within* that braced-init-list don't magically get special treatment just because the outer list happens to be used with an `auto` variable.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you mean... The special rules for `auto` don't go beyond one level deep. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I think the question I asked here is suitably answered, but this has raised other questions lol.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: Just remember: you're not really *supposed* to use braced-init-lists like this, so you should stop trying to do that.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the standard actually has an example of `auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list<int>`, in `[dcl.type.auto.deduct]` which I think means your sentence before the quote is incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisMM: I remembered the stupid thing wrong. The stupid thing is that `auto i = {3};` behaves differently from `auto i{3};`. Because that's totally uniform initialization...

Comment: @NicolBolas, yeah, the standard is a bit strange on that one, but at the same time, I _sort of_ understand why they would be different … _Sort of_